# JS regex to match zero-width position either loops forever or doesn't match at all

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

Okay, so I have this string `"nesˈo:tkʰo:x"`, and I want to get the index of all the zero-width positions that *don't* occur after any instance of the character `ˈ` (the IPA primary stress symbol). So in this case, those expected output would be 0, 1, 2, and 3 - the indices of the letters `nes` that occur before the one and only instance of `ˈ`, plus the `ˈ` itself.

I'm doing this with regex for reasons I'll get into in a bit. Regex101 confirms that `/(?=.*?ˈ)/` should match all 4 of those zero-width positions with JS' regex flavor... but I can't actually get JS to return them.

A simple setup might look like this:

```
let teststring = "nesˈo:tkʰo:x";
let re = new RegExp("(?=.*?ˈ)", "g");

while (result = re.exec(teststring)) {
    console.log("Match found at "+result.index);
}
```

...except that this loops forever. It seems to get stuck on the first match, which I understand has something to do with how `RegExp.exec` is supposed to auto-increment `RegExp.lastIndex` for global regexes, or something. But I also can't make the regex *not* global, or it won't return *all* the matches for strings like this where more than one match is expected.

Okay, so what if I manually increment `RegExp.lastIndex` to prevent it from looping?

```js
let teststring = "nesˈo:tkʰo:x";
let re = new RegExp("(?=.*?ˈ)", "g");

while (result = re.exec(teststring)) {
    if (result.index == re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    } else {
        console.log("Match found at "+result.index);
    }
}
```

Now it... prints out nothing at all. Now, to be fair, if `lastIndex` starts at 0 by default, and the index of the first match is 0, I half expect that to be skipped over... but why isn't it at least giving me 1, 2 and 3 as matches?

Now, I can already hear the chorus of "you don't need regex for this, just do `Array(teststring.indexOf("ˈ")).keys()` or something to generate `[0,1,2,3]`". That may work for *this specific example*, but the actual use case is a parser function that's supposed to be a general solution for "for this input string, replace all instances of A with B, if condition C is true, *unless* condition D is true". Those conditions might be something like "if A is at the end of the string" or "if A is right next to another instance of A" or "if A is between 'n' and 't'". *That* kind of complicated string matching problem is why the parser creates and executes regexes on the fly and why regex is getting involved, and it does work for *almost* everything except this one annoying edge case, which I'd rather not have to refactor the entire mechanism of the parser to deal with if I don't have to.

Comment: The problem is that `exec()` starts searching where the previous match ended. But when the match is zero-width, the end is the place where the previous match was found, and it will be found again.

Comment: I'm not sure why incrementing `lastIndex` doesn't solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.prototype.matchAll()` to get all the matches.

```js
let teststring = "nesˈo:tkʰo:x";
let re = new RegExp("(?=.*?ˈ)", "g");

[...teststring.matchAll(re)].forEach(result =>
  console.log("Match found at " + result.index)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.search()` returns the index of a match. `.exec()` returns an array of the match. Note a look ahead `(?=)` isn't needed, a standard capture group `()` suffices.

```js
const str =`nesˈo:tkʰo:x",`;
const rgx = /(.*?ˈ)/;

let first = str.search(rgx);
let last = rgx.exec(str)[0].length - 1;

console.log('Indices: '+first+' - '+(first + last)+' \nLength: '+(last+1));
```